# fmap print value doesn't print anything

Tags: haskell, functor

Why does the following doesn't print anything:

```
λ> fmap print (pure 2)
```

Whereas something like this works:

```
λ> fmap id (pure 2)
2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow the types:

```
fmap print (pure 2) :: Applicative f => f (IO ())
fmap id (pure 2)    :: (Num b, Applicative f) => f b
```

Lets replace `f` with `IO`:

```
fmap print (pure 2) :: IO (IO ())      -- #1
fmap id (pure 2)    :: (Num b) => IO b -- #2
```

Now you can clearly see that #2 is an action with a numeric result, whereas #1 is an action with another action as a result.

Also, GHCi has the following [rules about interactive evaluation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#id483385):

> ### 2.4. Interactive evaluation at the prompt
>
> When you type an expression at the prompt, GHCi immediately evaluates and prints the result:
>
> #### 2.4.1. I/O actions at the prompt
>
> GHCi does more than simple expression evaluation at the prompt. If you type something of type `IO a` for some `a`, then GHCi executes it as an IO-computation.
>
> Furthermore, GHCi will print the result of the I/O action if (and only if):
>
> - The result type is an instance of `Show`.
> - The result type is not ().

Since `IO a` is not an instance of `Show`, it won't print the result of the IO action.

Comment: @josejuan: Nothing, from a theoretical point of view. But in my opinion the information is scattered throughout your post, whereas I try to bundle things in a concise way. Intermediate haskellers see the problem immediately in the first three lines, whereas less advanced haskellers can see it easier without the `Applicative` in the next code listing and spot the `IO (IO ())` problem pretty fast. And even if one doesn't, the final sentence provides an explanation. But that could be just my opinion.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But all people get the response with just "Your expression return a computation (no perform it)" if is intermediate haskeller he understand "return a computation" if not then he must to learn about that. Your response (of course in my opinion) is not more clear than mine. It's ok anyway.

Comment: For this answer to be complete, it would be nice to briefly discuss how ghci chooses what to do with an expression. Specifically: `IO` actions get executed, and their result is either printed (if it is an instance of `Show` and is not `()`) or discarded otherwise; and non-`IO` values always get printed (possibly resulting in a "no instance of `Show`" error). This explains why things of type `IO (IO a)` do not get printed: the outer `IO` action gets executed, but the inner `IO` action is discarded because there is no `Show` instance for `IO`.

Answer (score 2):

Your expression return a computation (no perform it).

You want

```
fmap print (pure 2) >>= id
```

with that, we get your computation and run it inside monad.

Look your types

```
fmap print (pure 2) :: Applicative f => f (IO ())
```

Note

```
fmap print (pure 2) >>= id            -- #1
```

is very different (but same "visual" result) than

```
fmap id (pure 2)                      -- #2
```

with #1 we take a computation and run it inside monad **printing a number**

with #2 we take a number and get value through `fmap` **returning a number**

(looking types again

```
fmap id (pure 2) :: (Num b, Applicative f) => f b
```