# fmap putStrLn getLine does not perform IO

Tags: haskell

The title said it all, actually. I can't understand why this following code does not actually print "Hello World" as opposed of what `>>=` does.

```
main = fmap putStrLn getLine
```

Currently, here is my line of reasoning, please check if it has any fallacy.

If we compare `fmap` with `>>=`

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

In bind, the context, or in IO terms "World" the first `m` and the second `m` is entirely different aside of the types. `(a -> m b)` essentially recreates a new "World". This is not true in Functor, the context `f` are the same hence side effects are impossible.

Now, if that's indeed the case, why doesn't the compiler gives a warning when we try to `fmap` an effectful IO to an existing IO Monad?

Comment: Add `main :: IO ()` and you will notice the mistake. It is good practice to add explicit type signatures to all top-level equations.

Comment: A related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24549610/fmap-print-value-doesnt-print-anything

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're almost there. What is the type of `fmap putStrLn`?

```
putStrLn      ::              String -> IO ()
fmap          :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b    
fmap putStrLn :: Functor f => f String -> f (IO ())
```

And as a result `fmap putStrLn getLine` will be `IO (IO ())`, that is, an IO action, which contains *another* IO action. There's no need for a warning<sup>*</sup>, after all, this could be what you intended. The compiler cannot determine whether you wanted `m (m a)` or `m a`.

That's actually the power of a monad, it has an operation which enables you to join those actions:

```
join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
-- join x = x >>= id
```

---

<sup>* except maybe for the missing type signature. You can tell GHC to warn you about those with `-fwarn-missing-signatures`. See [warnings and sanity-checking](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.4/html/users_guide/options-sanity.html).</sup>

Comment: An `IO` action that yields another `IO` action is normally unlikely to be the right thing, though. But as you say, this is not for the compiler to judge.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I've seen (sub-expressions) of type `IO (IO a)` arise naturally around concurrency; while a lock is held (or in some other critical section) you calculate an action to perform after the lock is released (or the critical section is left).

Comment: what about [```-fwarn-wrong-do-bind:```](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/options-sanity.html) ?